# Hyperlink opens to about:blank regardless of where it's viewed

Tags: html, hyperlink

Basically my problem is that I have coded a really simple webpage to have various links to services running on my media server.  The computer in question is running Windows 8.1 Pro, has IIS running (but not every option was checked, I'd have to double check that).

Here is my code:

```
<a href="192.168.0.6:32400/web">
<img src="WWW/plex_logo.png" width="279px"/><br />
Plex
</a>
```

With the goal being that that it will open the Plex web page.  The IP address is the address of the computer running the Plex server, but regardless if I launch it on the same computer as the server, or another computer within my LAN, it just goes to `about:blank`

Comment: Do you get the correct page when you navigate to http://192.168.0.6:32400/web ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.  After noticing my code here, I realized that I left out the `http://` in my links.  Putting them there makes them work.